# Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed (after sending post form)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have form with method="post" in jsp page with action equals the same page. Then, I want to do sendredirect, but I already did forward by sending form.
What to do?

```
<form:form action="register" method="post" modelAttribute="userForm">
```

Comment: are you getting exception?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you want to send a redirect, you can't send any other kind of response. What do you want the flow to be in terms of HTTP request/response pairs?

Comment: are you saying you have same page on form `action`?

Comment: @NiteshVirani yes, see code

Comment: @JonSkeet look at the code

Comment: I'm not going to follow a pastebin link for code that should be in the question - and code only says what it *does*, not what you're *trying* to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to execute sendRedirect from page with method POST and it throws exception

Comment: @Elishanto: Well yes it would - read my comments earlier on. Do you understand that a redirect gives a different HTTP response code? As I said, you should think about what you want the requests and responses to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the redirect I was looking for without a "response already committed" error, I used a JSTL EL redirect tag between if statements in the JSP. This allowed the page to automatically redirect early enough in the rendering, so it didn't trigger an error.

```
%>
<c:redirect url="/"/>
<%
```

Comment: Note: this solution only works if there is minimal content is above the redirect tag. Redirecting from a JSP is huge red flag that "you are doing it wrong." (older, model 1 type web app design) Any redirect/forward decision should be made in controllers/filters, before the JSP is invoked.